# Why is editting in QGIS producing invalid geometry in PostgreSQL database?

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry, editing

I am editing a boundary in QGIS(3.10.8-A Coruña) and facing an issue when writing the back to PostGIS (10.13).

The workflow I am following is:

1. Download data from PostGIS connection in QGIS
2. Edit a boundary by: toggle editor on, switch on vertex tool and switch on snapping tool
3. Move the boundary to the desired location
4. Save the edits --> send the data back to the server.

When looking in the PostGIS database for the record and attempting to display the edited polygon it states "unsupported geometries not rendered", previously it would draw the polygon. [image]

Therefore, how do I edit the boundary without causing the geometry error?

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the Question to specify the exact release of all software and the exact geometry error. Screenshots would help.

Comment: Do you mean that you are using PostGIS 3.0 with PostgreSQL 10.13? I was thinking of screenshots of the polygon, but at this point, I think `ST_AsText` of the geometry, before and after would be more useful.

Comment: Are you using pgAdmin to display the features?

Comment: Does the edited geometry look ok in QGIS, even if you download it again from PostGIS?